# In Spark Java session is null after redirect

Tags: java, java-8, spark-java

I'm in the very beggining of creating my first web app on Spark. The application is very simple: it is custom random number generator.

On the first screen form takes two numbers (range of random number generation). I want to redirect users to the first screen if their input values are wrong and make validation on the server side. I want also to display wrong values to the user.

However, when I try to redirect to first page and save user input values in session.attributes they are not saved, because session is null.

My code is that simple:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/random", (req, res) -> {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            if (req.session(false) != null) {
                model.put("from", req.session().attribute("from"));
                model.put("to", req.session().attribute("to"));
            }

            return render(model, "/random/index.hbs");
        });

        get("/random/generator", (req, res) -> {
            // assume we got wrong values (i.e. not integers)
            // from - is a lower bound or random number generation
            // to - is an upper bound of random number generation
            String fromStr = req.queryParams("from");
            String toStr = req.queryParams("to");
            // checking for correctness and actions if correct are not included for brevity
            req.session().attribute("from", fromStr);
            req.session().attribute("to", toStr);
            res.redirect("/random");
            return null;
        });
    }

    private static String render(Map<String, Object> model, String viewName) {
        return new HandlebarsTemplateEngine().render(new ModelAndView(model, viewName));
    }
```

What is the reason for session being null? How can I achieve saving input values? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What URL are you navigating to? How do you set the query params?

Comment: @SHG http://localhost:4567/random/generator?from=0&to=5, for example. They come from form on the page, that has two inputs with names "from" and "to", method "get" and action "/random/generator".

Comment: It did work for me, are you sure you're doing exactly what you're saying?

Comment: @SHG my code is a bit more more complicated: there are few lines to check if "from" and "to" values are integers and that to is greater than from. But generally it follows described pattern. Moreover, I can see attributes attached to the session before redirect. But after, session disappears.

Comment: As I said, the code you published here worked for me. So try to run only it and see if it works as expected. If it is, add the rest of the code line by line and see what breaks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing caches solved the problem.